# Does Elitzur's theorem say anything about theories which are NOT gauge theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

Does [Elitzur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%27s_theorem) say anything about theories which are NOT gauge theories? I was wondering what happens if one considers scalar sector, or massive spin-1 field with a bare mass included in the Lagrangian.